# Debugging multiple projects under VS2012 - Main project invokes a sub-project

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution that has 2 projects. The main one and the one that is called with CreateProcess() from the main program.

The main one is a win32 program and the second a console application. I use the win32 program to invoke the console app and have it do its thing. My problem is, I want to be able to debug the console app once it's invoked with CreateProcess.

How can I accomplish this? or Can I accomplish this?

I'm also a little confused with the [Debugger API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as I want Visual Studio to be the debugger, instead of me creating the debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I agree with Scott's answer then, nothing to add. Use DebugBreak();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call DebugBreak(); at the start of the console process. When it hits that call you will be able to start a new instance of Visual Studio to debug the console process.